# Return an image from an Apiary call

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

How do I return an image from an apiary call?

```
## first image [/image/369]
### Complete [GET]
+ Response 200 (image/png)
xxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Turner, here is the declaration code in apiari for this method :

```
## first image [/image/369]
### Complete [GET]
+ Response 200 (image/png)

    + Body
    ‰PNG XXXXXXXXXXXXFZFZGEDHDSRGFEThERGEDFG
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: What should XXXXXX image XXXXXX be?

Should it be base64 encoding of binary that is then escaped for markdown?

Comment: you're right it's the image file returned, see my modified post

Comment: it's the content of the image file that would be in the body (take care of apiary requierement with indentation ! :)

Comment: How do I encode a binary image into text in apiary?

Comment: ok, I see you should encode in [ANSI ISO-8859](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_character_set). But apiari isn't a code generator, it's oriented to produce geek docs.

Comment: normaly in order to add images, you should return the uri of the image and then make a frontend call to the image uri. You shouldn't pass the image stream thrue your webserver, it will cost a lot of time/cpu. That is precious. see [apiary movie](http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#movies) and search for image, you will see that the returned element of your api is an uri. Give me some feedback. enjoy :)